# How do MLB Managers do the lineup card on Jackie Robinson Day?

Tags: baseball, mlb

How are lineup cards and official scorebooks recorded on Jackie Robinson Day? Do the managers/scorekeepers use the players' regular numbers, or is it literally "42" for every player's number?

Answer (score 5):

According to multiple sources I've seen, they don't even put jersey numbers on the lineup card, so I don't believe they put anything even on Jackie Robinson day.  Here is a picture of a game used card used in the Cubs vs Reds game last season during Jackie Robinson day, and no numbers are present.  The only information present is Batting Order position, Name, and Position number.

[image: Lineup Card]

Comment: Ah very good, thank you. How about for scorebooks? Every scorebook I am finding shows player numbers - cannot find an official one for April 15, though.